# How to set fixed width and height in an alertBox?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have this alertbox

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Instructions.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_layout, null);
        alertDialog.setView(view);

        final AlertDialog newDialog = alertDialog.create();
```

I try to do this:

```
newDialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```

It does not work!

What do I have to do? Thanks

Comment: you can set the height and width in xml file itself R.layout.alert_dialog_layout

Comment: I want to set it manually

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this line :

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```

after `alertDialog.close` line and not before.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is a problem (if you want I edit the code). I have a footer in this alert dialog. With your code, the alertdialog dimension became fixed but if greater than original the footer isn't align on bottom but I have white space. How can I fix it?

Comment: If your original problem has been solved then please post a new question for the new issue. Every one will able to see the question and will help you. If my answer helped you, please vote it and accept it. Thank you.